# What does the end of Nina Forever mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, nina-forever

In the end of the movie [*Nina Forever*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2885628/) (2015), Rob walks away and Holly makes space for someone in her bed and goes to sleep. What is that ending supposed to signify?

Answer (score 1):

[This source has an answer](http://www.themoviespoiler.com/2016Spoilers/NinaForever.html):

> “I’m Sorry,” Rob says. Holly tells Rob it was never him that was the problem it was her. Holly had romanticized Rob’s tragic link with Nina, and felt that she could “fix” him. Yet, her whole attraction was apparently around saving a guy with a dead girlfriend, so Nina had been linked to her from the very beginning. While Rob finally found his closure and is no longer haunted, Holly apparently always will since she idealized the tragic end of their romance.

I just watched the movie and this is a good enough explanation for me!

Comment: Yes, but why is rob free? Why has Nina spared him?

Comment: He healed himself and truly got over her, with the help of Holly. He even has a closure meeting with Nina's parents